# Switch between multiple views in the same viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, menuitem

I'm using the Side-out-Navigation-panel in this [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path) and it is easy for me. 
Now I want to do it in storyboard and I want when select item from list panel to switch between different views in the centerViewController like uitableView or uiview. 
exactly like facebook.

how can I make switch between different views in the same viewController?
Hope anyone got my mean.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use [UIView transitionFromView:toView]

Comment: could you show me how to use it, please?

Comment: added the answer, try it

Comment: What sort of views do you want to switch between? From your comments below, it sounds like you'd be better off switching between viewcontrollers, rather than just presenting lots of different views within a single viewcontroller.

Comment: That's because I'm using this http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path and in the left side there are a table of my views and I want when select one of then from table to switch it in the centerViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Example](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers) helped me. It is what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.someView toView:self.tableView duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //completion block
    }];
```

Comment: Ok, but consider the I want to switch between 4 views, 3 of them are uitableview and I want to jump from one view to another exactly like facebook navigation meaning that in facebook I can jump from messages to news fed and from news fed to one group and so one, how can I get the current view in this function??

Comment: whenever user selects either message or newsfeed etc you want to show that view in centreViewController, right?

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: you have four views (A,B,C,D). lets say, you are now showing view A, and now you want B to take place of A with some animation.then use above method ,in fromView give A and toView give B and give type of animation in options. It now animates from A to B.similarly with other views.

Comment: I want to jump dynamically from A to B, C, or D - from B to A, C or D and so on, how could I do that .. I'm not want it static.

Comment: its not static. suppose you decide to jump from A -> C, on some click operation.Then in that click method add fromView A and toView C. 
Or reference those views in UIView *formView =(A or B or ..) UIView *toView = (B or C..). [UIView fromView:fromView toView:toView];

Comment: I am having the same issue. Has anyone figured out this for swift?