# Swift - How to segue between two child view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**Problem**

I have 3 VCs named P, A and B.

A and B are embedded in P (P is the parent VC).

I want to have a button on P, that when pressed, switches between A and B (whichever one isn't showing, segue to it).

Here is the picture of what I mean

[image]

**Attempted Solution**

I tried following examples such as

[ContainerView controller Sample](https://github.com/bartjacobs/ManagingViewControllersWithContainerViewControllers)

but this is simply showing and hiding two VCs. I want to segue between them (specifically using the "Flip Horizontal" animation).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between multiple views in the same viewcontroller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363563/switch-between-multiple-views-in-the-same-viewcontroller)

Comment: This might helpful for you: https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [UISegmentedController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol) what you want for this very specific case?

Comment: I would like to use a single button rather than a segmented controller though. To be exact I would like to use a bar button item that is in a navigation bar. Here is a video to the exact effect I am going for: https://youtu.be/EgU7BfOJ3BE (I am tapping on the List/Map button in the top right of the screen)